# Du bist mir wieder einer

Tags: meaning

I have heard the following dialogue in the TV series "How To Sell Drugs Online (Fast)":

- Und heute Abend? Was geht?
- Sie kennen ja ihren Sohn. Wir gehen zu Lisas Party. Da versorgen wir alles mit Drogen. Und gegen Mitternacht kommt der Bus mit den Nutten.
- Du bist mir wieder einer!

What does "du bist mir wieder einer" mean? The literal translation "you are again one for me" does not make any sense.

Comment: Any search results that does not explain much? https://www.redensarten-index.de/suche.php?suchbegriff=~~Du%20bist%20mir%20vielleicht%20einer!%20Du%20bist%20mir%20ja%20einer!&bool=relevanz&suchspalte%5B%5D=rart_ou

Comment: For translation requests, you should consider a page like DeepL: https://www.deepl.com/translator#de/en/Du%20bist%20mir%20wieder%20einer! If that doesn't help, questions are welcomed.

Comment: @user unknown -- There is an idiom involved here, and DeepL isn't familiar with it in this case so it's not much help; same with Google Translate. Idiom dictionaries can be useful, but for learners it's difficult to tell where the idiom part begins and ends. It's like asking "On which word does the sentence start to not make sense?" Plus there can be variations in phasing that make an exact match difficult to find. Plus, while Redensarten is very handy, it is a bit light on detail, so it would be nice so see someone expand on the entry.

Comment: einer = ein Schlawiner

Comment: @RDBury: Wie Du siehst, gibt es von mir kein Votum, die Frage zu schließen. Ich kann nämlich nicht beurteilen, ob die Übersetzung von DeepL im Englischen funktioniert oder nicht. Aus Erfahrung weiß ich aber, dass DeepL einer Wort-für-Wort-Übersetzung meist deutlich überlegen ist, und auch Google-Translate aussticht, aber das nur nebenbei. Des Weiteren habe ich ja geschrieben, dass man, wenn das Ergebnis nicht überzeugt, eingeladen ist, hier zu fragen. Dann sollte man etwas Besseres als eine WfW-Übersetzung als Basis aber auch anführen.

Comment: @userunknown Vielen Dank für die Informationen, aber ich versuche immer, einen idiomatischen Ausdruck mit DeepL Translator zu übersetzen, bevor ich ihn hier veröffentliche. Ich möchte nicht unhöflich sein, aber solange Sie nicht mehr Details/Kontext anfordern oder die Frage beantworten, sehe ich keinen Sinn darin, etwas zu posten.

Comment: @userunknown -- Ja, die Frage war nicht sehr klar, aber ich nahm einfach an, es war eine Frage des Idioms und keine Übersetzungsanfrage. Das Programm hat jedenfalls englische Untertitel, also sollte eine einfache Übersetzung nicht das Problem sein. Ich weiß, dass diese Website eine Menge Übersetzungsaufträge erhält und viele davon von Leuten kommen, die nicht wirklich an Deutsch interessiert sind. Sie haben Recht, dass die Leute in diesen Fällen auf DeepL umgeleitet werden sollten.

Answer (score 2):

The underlying idiom is "Du bist mir einer!" or "Du bist mir ja einer!", which is hard to translate because even in a concrete situation, it can be hard or impossible for the recipient to discern if it is meant approvingly or disapprovingly.

Google and DeepL translate "Du bist mir ja einer!" correctly with

> You are droll!
> You are something else!
> You are one hell of a guy!

So it can be approving, but it doesn't have to be.

In your sentence, it is modified with "wieder" (again), and that makes it hard to find the idiom on the internet or for algorithms to translate it.

Comment: So the "mir" in this expression is purely idiomatic and indeed makes no sense?

Comment: It does make sense, it's a [dativus ethicus](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dativ#dativus_ethicus). Rather out of fashion and therefore mostly idiomaticised, though.

Comment: Which always reminds me of the beginning of König Ödipus: "τίνας ποθ’ ἕδρας τάσδε μοι θοάζετε", _was sitzt ihr **mir** auf diesen Stufen hier?_

Answer (score -2):

"Du bist mir" is abbreviated from "Du bist für mich" and means "you look to me". "Wieder" is just indicating reappearance, so the speaker knows the general behavioral pattern of the listener and recognizes it. "Einer" is an elliptical/incomplete hint at some unspecified, but considered inappropriate type of person; one might add three dots and imagine someone raising a warning finger.